# Kill SSHd Process in Ubuntu

Tags: bash

..Hi, does anyone know a short script on how to kill sshd for 10 minutes and then back up for 10 minutes continually? Please have mercy on me, I'm a newbie.

Thanks,
joe.

Comment: Depends upon the release of Ubuntu that you are running. Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with some basic bash scripting. You have to use `sleep` in order to add a delay, as well as the "while loop", mostly known for being the infinite loop. Example:

`nano sshd-loop.sh`

```
while : 
do
    systemctl stop sshd
    sleep 10m 
    systemctl start sshd
    sleep 10m
done
```

I am no expert on this language but I believe that should work. If you intend to run it on the background you can add `&`, `disown` or `nohup` at the end of `sudo bash sshd-loop.sh` depending on your needs as each option is different, you can find more information about them [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/).

If you would like to check the status of the service just run `sudo systemctl status sshd`